# How can I use notistick/(any snackbar) with redux-toolkit and react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-toolkit

I want suggestion where and how should I write my snackbar, so it should give notification if data is fetched or if any error occurs while fetching.
There are many example for the same, but my case is different because of folder structure.
Example:
src/api.js

```
  const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: `/`,
});
 export async function fetchData(data) {
  try {
    const res = await API.get(`/endpoint`);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

src/slice.js

```
import * as REQUESTS from "./api.js";
const initialState = {
  data: []
}

export const dataSlice= createSlice({
  name: "dataSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setData(state,action) {
      const { data } = action.payload;
      state.data = data.map((item) => item);
    },
}
})

export const { setData} = dataSlice.actions

//THUNK
export const fetchData= () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    
    const { Data,Err } = await REQUESTS.fetchData();
     //If no err snackbar/toast should show fetched successfully.
     // I called snackbar here but snackbar library gives an error, says it should called from within a component.

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

src/app.jsx

```
 //USING USE SELECTION GET DATA FROM STORE
const displayData= props => (
    <h1>{data}</h1>
)
```

Now where and how can I use my snackbar to get status from server if it fetched or not!
this is just a mock-up of my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a link to [redux implementation example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/iamhosseindhv/notistack/tree/master/examples/redux-example?file=/redux/actions.js) in [notistack documentation](https://www.iamhosseindhv.com/notistack/demos#redux-/-mobx-example). Look at it.

Short summary:

- you need to create your own action creator that will be dispatched in your action creator `fetchData`. This action creator will dispatch action of type `ENQUEUE_SNACKBAR` with all necessary information you would need for displaying the notification (see actions.js in example).
- your reducer will store this notification in an array to allow multiple notification come at the same moment (see reducer.js in example).
- you need to create a new component for displaying your stored notifications (see Notifier.js in example). In this component you will call the own `enqueueSnackbar` from notistack. And also don't forget to dispatch action of type `REMOVE_SNACKBAR` for removing notification from your redux store in notistack `onExited` handler (also look at Notifier.js in example for that).

Comment: how you trigger the notistack, based on question above, we should put the trigger (dispatch) on fetchData function